# Pseudo-code program for handling errors

Tags: c, syntax-error

I want to write a program in pseudocode which will identify incorrect uses of "#" or "%" in a C/C++ source file. 
It sounds simple, but I am not sure on how to write/describe in "pseudo code" the position on which that sign appears, whether or not is is before/after a variable name, for instance.

Should I use something like:

```
  If "#" after var_a
       then "Error!"
    elseif before ";"
        .... and so on
```

or should I use something like #_ASCII_code is_after "symbol"....

I really cannot figure how to describe these particular situations in pseudo-code.

I have to mention that I read about Pseudo-code on the internet.( i have used the search button)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pseudo-code in C? Do you mean using macros to uncompile some stuff in your code?

Comment: c and c++ source will be very different to parse.

Comment: No. Let's say you have a C source (let only C, not C++)file that contains errors. The idea of the pseudocode program is to describe how the compiler would notice these errors and how it should handle them.

Comment: Where does the pseudocode flavour you use come from ? Pseudocode is not a language, and writings conventions vary.

Comment: I did not want to use it, but our teacher thinks it would be good for us to learn it by writing, sorry, describing, this "program". Also, the teacher wants us to draw a diagram based on this code, a so called logical scheme, I think

Comment: Identifying incorrect uses of # and % requires you to write a full C parser. I doubt you want to do that. In my opinion this problem is far too big for a (normally short) pseudo code.

Comment: It's better to begin with pseudo code instead of C or C++ because it saves you from syntax errors, and you can directly use the appropriate refinement level. But it cannot save you from knowing what you want to do : begin by listing correct (or incorrect) use cases up to an acceptable level, think of comments, litteral strings ... In short : 1. specify, 2. describe in pseudo code, 3. code (any language), 4 test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work because it's [too simple](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple). The solution is a multi-step process called "[parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)" until you end up with an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree):

- First, you need to convert the stream of characters in the source file into tokens (`b = a ++` -> `ID ASSIGN ID INCREMENT`).
- Then you need a [LL parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) to convert those into higher level rules. The rules for a whole source file are usually called AST - [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

That tree now allows you to write pseudo code:

```
For all AST nodes with the text representation "#"
    if the previous sibling is a variable
        ...
    else if the next sibling is ";"
        ...
```

Comment: I really like your citation ! But until OP says what he wants to do, I'm not sure he really needs a full parser. Especially as it is a teacher assignment ...

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code is a form of specification. If it is too difficult to write this specification in pseudo code, then write it first in natural language, for example "All variables shall be perfixed by '#'." from which automatically follows that a variable not prefixed by '#' is an error.

Writing a specification can make sure the problem is well-described. Following this, you can start with pseudo code, which then is a form of design, and you can end up with writing the real program, which can be in any language or mechanism. For example, you can decide the solution lends itself for a yacc script, or it is simple enough that you can code it directly in C or C++.

As pseudo code is not well defined, it can lead to requirements being poorly described in this pseudo-implementation. Going from a poor pseudo-implementation to a real implementation then results in a poor implementation (see also: bugs).

Maybe best not to use pseudo code at all.